# AnyLogic Initialize Parameters Before Sim Run

Tags: initialization, anylogic

I'm definitely an AnyLogic newbie.  I am trying to setup an initialization period to initialize a couple of defined variables for say 10 seconds prior to each simulation run.  I want the output to show this "stabilization" period before the actual simulation begins.  Can this be done from the "Before Simulation Run" section on the Simulation properties?  If so, how?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no pre-build warm-up period setup.

Easiest way I found is to add a statechart to Main where you move from a warmup state to a "running" state after some time.

Whenever you collect data, first check if `myStateChart.isStateActive(Main.running)` so you only collect when not warminp up